# Delete records from Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I'm trying to create an SSIS Package. I have a query to extract data from multiple tables in Oracle Database and this is my Source in the SSIS Data Flow (OLE DB Source). I have to look for matched records with the destination (SQL Server Database) - for this have used "Lookup" transformation and delete the matched records from my source, i.e., Oracle Database. I have created a data flow but I don't know how to proceed further in deleting the records.

[image: Data Flow Image]

In the OLE DB Command editor, how do I write the SQL Command to delete the matched records from the Oracle database? The database doesn't have a table name. Can I use the same query that I used to pull the records and instead of `select`, use `delete`?

I'm not sure if what I'm asking makes sense, but I desperately need HELP.

PS: I don't have any formal education or work experience related to IT. This is my first assignment at work and I'm really interested in developing IT Skills.

Comment: You can convert your select satement into a delete, or use delete where your PK/ID is IN (select list of Ids here using your select)  no need for a data flow task for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is this valid? "Delete where CustomerID =?" Will this delete all the records using this customerid?

Comment: If that is your table structure, but you have to say delete FROM tablename where customerID =   for one record at a time, if you are trying to delete all the rercords freom your select it would be delete from tablename where customterID in (select customerID from yourtable where clause

Comment: What would the table name be in this case? I have a query to pull records from an oracle database (It pulls data from multiple tables within the same database) - This step is in "OLE DB Source" . I don't know the table name though.That is my concern?

Comment: Sorry missed it was cross database query.  The way to do this then would be take the ID's from your oracle table, import them into a temp table inside SQL, and then run the query I posted above on SQL to delete the records from your SQL table.  Then drop the temp table  (or if this is ongoing create a Stage table to house the ID's and just clear it out as first step in your process.

Comment: This will be an on going activity( running the package). Does creating staging table and performing delete matched records, remove these records from the database itself?

Comment: If you delete it from your table in SQL server yes.  You need to know the table names, data structure and everything on the SQL side you want to delete the data from